# TreeMap.get() return Null even key exists

Tags: java, treemap

I am trying to get from TreeMap but it return null even the key exist.
HashCode and eqauls is based on word only. Comparable is based on freqency.

```
    public static void main(){
        TreeMap<Word,Integer> test = new TreeMap<>();
        test.put(new Word("pqr",12),1);
        test.put(new Word("abc",2),1);

        Integer prq = test.get(new Word("pqr",1));
        System.out.println(prq);
        prq = test.get(new Word("pqr",12));
        System.out.println(prq);
    }


    public class Word implements Comparable<Word>{
        String word;
        Integer freq;

        public Word(String word, Integer freq) {
            this.word = word;
            this.freq = freq;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (!(o instanceof Word)) return false;

            Word word1 = (Word) o;

            return word.equals(word1.word);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return word.hashCode();
        }


        @Override
        public int compareTo(Word o) {
            return this.freq.compareTo(o.freq);
        }
    }
```

Output is like 
null
1

Comment: show us the Word class please

Answer (score 2):

In your `compareTo` method it is comparing the frequency. So if the frequency is same it will be equal.

to compare the words you can use

```
return this.word.compareTo(o.word);
```

or to compare both word and frequency you can use

```
return this.word.compareTo((o.word)) *  this.freq.compareTo(o.freq);
```

**EDIT**

Now as you need to sort using the frequency so instead of using comparable you can use `Comparator`. Use the above comparators to create the Map. And use your previous comprator to sort.

while creating

```
        TreeMap<Word, Integer> test = new TreeMap<Word, Integer>(
            new Comparator<Word>() {
                public int compare(Word word, Word o) {
                    return word.word.compareTo((o.word));
                }
            });
```

and while sorting

```
    Collections.sort(new LinkedList(test.keySet()), new Comparator<Word>() {
        public int compare(Word word, Word o) {
            return word.freq.compareTo((o.freq));
        }
    });
```

Comment: I want sorting based on frequency

Comment: @MayurB.. check the updated answer whether it helps you

Comment: @StunPike : I would have used HashMap if i want to sort it outside.

Answer (score 1):

`TreeMap` uses the `compareTo` method to decide key ordering and key equality.

Since your `Word` class uses the `freq` field in its `compareTo` method, any two `Word`s  with the same `freq` are considered equal.

From the [documentation of `TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> ... but a sorted map performs all key comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two keys that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted map, equal.

Answer (score 0):

this code here is not working if the class word don't override properly Equals and hashcode...

```
TreeMap<Word,Integer> test = new TreeMap<>();
test.put(new Word("pqr",12),1);
test.put(new Word("abc",2),1);

Integer prq = test.get(new Word("pqr",1));
System.out.println(prq);
prq = test.get(new Word("pqr",12));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what exactly happen in the TreeMpa.get() method,

```
while (p != null) {
            int cmp = k.compareTo(p.key);
            if (cmp < 0)
                p = p.left;
            else if (cmp > 0)
                p = p.right;
            else
                return p;
        }
```

TreeMpa use **compareTo** method to find the value. so it will loop through all the item till **k.compareTo(p.key)** return 0

Comment: What is the way to fulfill my requirement. I want treemap to be sorted based on freq and key should be based on string word

Answer (score 0):

Since your **Word** class implements Comparable interface . So **TreeMap** uses **compareTo** method for comparing properties of objects.

If you want to get the object with same String "word" then implement compareTo method like

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Word o) {
    return this.word.compareTo(o.word);
}
```